# How should I organize this C project

Tags: c

I am doing this programming assignment in C. But I am confused as to how to organize it.

So, here is the situation. I have two tree implementations and declare their struct/includes/function prototypes and so on in two separate header files. Then I have two c source code for the two implementations. Now here comes the problem. I have one test c file (only one main function for running tests) for the ADTs of Trees. Since the two implementations are going to use the same test. How can I avoid making two copies of the same main.c file? when I include the header file of tree implementation1, I can do `gcc Tree_implementation1.c main.c`. But to do implementation2, I have to got back in the main source file and manually change the include to tree implementation2, and then I can use the same compilation command. How do I work around this to toggle between the two implementations with only one main.c?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you also tag this C++?

Comment: I was in my data structure class, and the book we used was really old.  Back then, they don't have OOP. So most interfaces are implemented using Pascal in functions. I implemented these mainly in C, but I also included some handy C++ classes like string, sstream and stuff. Therefore, I tagged it with C++ too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the preprocessor and a constant that you can set on the command line:

In your main.c:

```
#ifdef TREE_IMPL1
#include "TreeImplementation1.h"
#else
#include "TreeImplementation2.h"
#endif

// ...

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
#ifdef TREE_IMPL1
    // code for testing TreeImplementation1
#else
    // code for testing TreeImplementation2
#endif
}
```

When you compile, pass or omit `TREE_IMPL1` on the command line, or set it in your IDE:

```
gcc -DTREE_IMPL1 main.c ...
```

Comment: This is great! There are tons of options in gcc I have to learn. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Do your implementations have the same name? They shouldn't.

If (or when) they don't have the same name, you can just include both headers in `main.c` and test either one depending on some preprocessor directive.

```
//main.c
#include "Tree_implementation1.h"
#include "Tree_implementation2.h"

int main()
{
#ifdef TEST_FIRST
   testFirstTree();  //declared in Tree_implementation1.h
#else
   testSecondTree();  //declared in Tree_implementation2.h
#endif
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think your idea is essentially the same as above. Thanks for you help.

Comment: @zsljulius esentially, yes, but I suggest you include both files. That way, potential naming conflicts appear early on.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for your problem is using of dynamic interface.
Work the way like that:

```
#include "Imp_1.h"
#include "Imp_2.h"

typedef void (*TreeFunctionType1)(Tree,param);
typedef void (*TreeFunctionType2)(Tree);

typedef struct ITree
{
    TreeFunctionType1 func1;
    TreeFunctionType2 func2;
}ITree;

static ITree _Itree={0};

void SetImp(TreeFunctionType1 f1,TreeFunctionType2 f2)
{
    tree.func1 = f1;
    tree.func2 = f2;
}

/*Use only this functions in your Tests code*/
//{
void Func1(Tree tree,Param param)
{
    (*_Itree.func1)(tree,param);
}

void Func2(Tree tree)
{
    (*_Itree.func2)(tree);
}
//}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    SetImp(Imp_1_f1,Imp_1_f2);
    TestCode();
    SetImp(Imp_2_f1,Imp_2_f2);
    TestCode();
    return 0;
}
```